# Best site for juggling related questions

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What is the best Stack Exchange site to ask questions relating to all things juggling? Is there even a site that would be appropriate  for a question like this?

Comment: Looks like we [juggle](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=+juggling) on a number of sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what the questions are about. Some examples of the kind of question you would like to ask would really help.

If they involve or relate to the competitive aspects of the physical activity of juggling, I believe it would be justified as on-topic at [Sports Stack Exchange](https://sports.stackexchange.com/) (speaking as a moderator and long-term member there). We do not yet have a tag or questions about it, but we're happy to work on developing the relevant content.

If they are about personal or social aspects, and not *the competitive activity* of juggling, they will not be on-topic at Sports SE, sorry.

Answer (score -5):

For your question, MSE is a good place.

My [network-wide tagfinder query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1348631/tagfinder-network-wide?TagName=juggl#resultSet) shows that a tag with the "juggl" substring exists only on two sites: the https://stackoverflow.com and the https://security.stackexchange.com . In both cases it has only a symbolic meaning.

Thus, we have no such SE sites.

But, I think, maybe the https://sports.stackexchange.com could be some similar.

Comment: Sports is about *competitive* sports, I doubt juggling questions are welcomed.

Comment: @Glorfindel Possible, I do not know them. There is also a "performing" tag on the https://fitness.stackexchange.com , probably it is yet weaker match.