# Which site should I ask this question on?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would want to ask questions related to how to write with my non-dominant hand. On which site would this question be ideal?

Comment: Partial duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358781/323179

Comment: That's not one question it's 4 and therefore too broad.

Comment: Sports?????????

Comment: Exercise or physical therapy would be one question, and site.

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget It's immaterial now, since OP has edited them out of the question, but a) I don't think Sports.SE consider juggling, pen-spinning, or card-throwing to be competitive sports, and b) even if they did, it's unclear whether OP wants to ask about them in a competitive context. They don't answer questions about recreational activies.

Comment: Perhaps the Lifehacks stack might be worth exploring? I never visit it so I have no idea whether it is on-topic there but asking on the child meta might clarify.

Comment: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com

Comment: The answer to the question is the same as to “How do you get to Carnegie Hall?”